# How do you express it using the fetch API in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch

Now, I POST image data using ajax(jquery) as follows. The `image` is a `File` object.

```
async function postImage({ image }) {
  const result = await $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/images',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: image,
    processData: false,
    async: true,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    },
  });
  return result;
}
```

The result that return object is `{id: imageID}`.
How can I express this using the `Fetch API`? I couldn't get the `result` even if I did the following.

```
const result = await fetch('/api/images', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: image,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    },
  });
return result;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) returns a promise to a [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object, and that has a [`json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) method which returns another promise to the parsed response JSON.

```js
const response = await fetch('/api/images', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: image,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
  },
});
const result = await response.json();
```